# Cross-domain ajax request not executing in iOS Simulator using Phonegap

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, cross-domain

I'm just getting started with Phonegap and mobile development in general, and am stuck trying to get a call to $.ajax(...) to *do anything* when run from the iOS simulator or an iOS device - but my little app works fine both when run from a browser or from the Ripple emulator (http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/).

Also, I've familiarized myself with CORS, and my testing seems to indicate that my request/response headers are setup properly for cross-domain client-server communication. Using the Safari WebInspector's JS debugger to step through the execution (and monitoring my server's Apache logs), I've been able to determine that the call to xhr.send() never actually executes.

Once I realized this, I removed jQuery from the equation, in case I was setting up the $.ajax() request improperly, and I used the code below to create the CORS request (obtained from here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

In both cases (with and without jQuery), I've noticed in the debugger that after the call to xhr.open(...) the values of xhr.status and xhr.statusText are both set to "[Exception: DOMException]", which I'm assuming is what is preventing the xhr.send() from executing.

Also, my config.xml contains the line:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Here's the code to create and execute the request:

```
// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Helper method to parse the title tag from the response.
function getTitle(text) {
  return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>')[1];
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest() {
  // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
  var url = 'http://server.mylocalhost/api/action?arg1=foo';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var title = getTitle(text);
    alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Whoops, there was an error making the request.');
  };

  xhr.send();
}
```

Note: The url specified above in makeCorsRequest() mirrors the actual structure of the url I'm targeting in my application.

**My setup:**

- Full control of both ends of the ajax request
- Developing locally, with separate apache virtual hosts for the client and server (e.g., http://server.mylocalhost and http://mobile.mylocalhost)
- The latest versions of everything (Phonegap/Cordova, Xcode, Ripple, Chrome, Safari, Jquery, OSX/Mavericks, etc)

I feel like I must be missing something very basic...any ideas?

Also, I would prefer not to use JSONP.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a problem at the network (DNS) layer. It turns out that the Xcode iOS simulator ignores the host machine's /etc/hosts file, and there doesn't seem to be an equivalent way to control DNS in the simulator's environment. So, as far as I can tell, it's not possible to develop on a local dev machine using name-based virtual hosts...which seems quite a ridiculous limitation.

Since the iOS simulator evidently *does* know how to find "localhost", I fixed my problem by adding the following line to the VirtualHost container for the virtual host that is my target API endpoint (in the appropriate Apache conf file):

```
ServerAlias localhost
```

Then I changed the url in the makeCorsRequest() to something of the form:

```
var url = 'http://localhost/api/action?arg1=foo';
```

Making a similar change in the jQuery-based version of my code also worked.

There may be other/better ways to work around this sad restriction, but for now this fix has allowed me to get back to actually focusing on my application.